# Initializing custom map class object causes error C2783

Tags: c++, dictionary, tree, binary-tree

I recently implemented my own custom map class as std::map replacement for my C-runtime independent project. I know it might not be as efficient as std::map but it serves its purpose.

This is how that class including the required structs Pair and Node looks like (i removed most of the functions that are not related to my problem):

```
template< class T, class U >
class Map;

template< class T, class U >
struct Pair
{
    T first;
    U second;
};

template< class T, class U >
class Node
{
    friend class Map<T, U>;
public:
    T first;
    U second;

protected:
    Node<T, U>* pParent;
    Node<T, U>* pLeft;
    Node<T, U>* pRight;

public:
    Node(T SetFirst,
        U SetSecond,
        Node<T, U>* pSetParent)
    {
        this->first = SetFirst;
        this->second = SetSecond;
        this->pParent = pSetParent;
    }
};

template< class T, class U >
class Map
{
private:
    Node<T, U>* pRoot,
        *pCurrentNode;

private:
    template< typename N >
    static N Insert(const T& SetFirst,
        const U& SetSecond,
        Node<T, U>*& Leaf)
    {
        if (!Leaf)
        {
            Leaf = new Node<T, U>(SetFirst,
                SetSecond,
                nullptr);

            Leaf->pLeft = nullptr;
            Leaf->pRight = nullptr;

            return Leaf;
        }
        else if (SetFirst < Leaf->first)
        {
            if (Leaf->pLeft != nullptr)
                return Insert<N>(SetFirst,
                    SetSecond,
                    Leaf->pLeft);
            else
            {
                Leaf->pLeft = new Node<T, U>(SetFirst,
                    SetSecond,
                    Leaf);

                Leaf->pLeft->pLeft = nullptr;
                Leaf->pLeft->pRight = nullptr;

                return Leaf->pLeft;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Leaf->pRight != nullptr)
                return Insert<N>(SetFirst,
                    SetSecond,
                    Leaf->pRight);
            else
            {
                Leaf->pRight = new Node<T, U>(SetFirst,
                    SetSecond,
                    Leaf);

                Leaf->pRight->pLeft = nullptr;
                Leaf->pRight->pRight = nullptr;

                return Leaf->pRight;
            }
        }
    }

public:
    Map()
    {
        this->pRoot = nullptr;
        this->pCurrentNode = nullptr;
    }

    Map(const Map& SetMap)
    {
        this->pRoot = nullptr;
        this->pCurrentNode = nullptr;

        this->operator=(SetMap);
    }

    Map& operator=(Map& SetMap)
    {
        this->Clear();

        if (!SetMap.Empty())
        {
            for (auto it = SetMap.Begin(); it != nullptr; it = SetMap.Next())
                this->Insert(it->first,
                    it->second,
                    this->pRoot);
        }

        return *this;
    }
};
```

Because my project is C-runtime independent i have to take care of initializing static variables like some Map objects i use in my project on my own so i did that like for example
"Keys = Map ();".
When compiling that code it gave me an error C2783 basically saying something like "template argument for "N" could not be deduced" (i translate those errors into English on my own because my Visual Studio is set to German).
After a while i saw that i did not specify any N for the insert call in operator= so i started thinking about why i would even need that N and decided to remove it from the function and all places where Insert is called in the class.
After doing that, the Insert function looked like this:

```
static Node<T, U>* Insert(const T& SetFirst,
        const U& SetSecond,
        Node<T, U>* Leaf)
    {
        if (!Leaf)
        {
            Leaf = new Node<T, U>(SetFirst,
                SetSecond,
                nullptr);

            Leaf->pLeft = nullptr;
            Leaf->pRight = nullptr;

            return Leaf;
        }
        else if (SetFirst < Leaf->first)
        {
            if (Leaf->pLeft != nullptr)
                return Insert(SetFirst,
                    SetSecond,
                    Leaf->pLeft);
            else
            {
                Leaf->pLeft = new Node<T, U>(SetFirst,
                    SetSecond,
                    Leaf);

                Leaf->pLeft->pLeft = nullptr;
                Leaf->pLeft->pRight = nullptr;

                return Leaf->pLeft;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Leaf->pRight != nullptr)
                return Insert(SetFirst,
                    SetSecond,
                    Leaf->pRight);
            else
            {
                Leaf->pRight = new Node<T, U>(SetFirst,
                    SetSecond,
                    Leaf);

                Leaf->pRight->pLeft = nullptr;
                Leaf->pRight->pRight = nullptr;

                return Leaf->pRight;
            }
        }
    }
```

However after compiling this i did no longer get a compiler error BUT instead a "Warning C4239 Non standard extension "Argument" Converting from "Map &"" appeared in the output window multiple times which when clicking on it redirected me to code lines like "TestMap = Map();" (this one is obviously just code i added to my project for testing things related to this problem) and when running it my program crashed.
What exactly is wrong with my class and do i actually need that "N" template in Insert or can it be solved somehow else?

Comment: Was it tagged as "C"? Lol i kind of messed up the tags as this is my first question and it was complaining about me adding to many tags

Comment: @Paranaix That's right i didn't notice that but the problem is that the way the operator= uses Begin and Next makes it not possible to change it to a const reference because that way of iterating through SetMap actually changes the pCurrentNode member of SetMap.

Comment: @ccman32 Well, and that's what constness is for. If you have to modify something it's not const. Either figure out a way around it or don't declare it as const. (Hint: having a current node member is a bad idea obviously)

Comment: @Paranaix i don't really feel like using a const_cast for that, however there must still be something wrong that caused the crash i mentioned because it obviously happened after i changed Insert so it no longer takes the template type N. Would you mind explaining what you mean with "fuckup with raw pointers" (i guess you are talking about uninitialized pointers pointing to some random crap in the memory) and what code you are referring to if there is any? This is how the class currently looks like: http://pastebin.com/YLt3MQh2

Comment: @Paranaix I managed to fix the crash problem. I accidentally changed the Leaf param in Insert from Node<T, U>*& to Node<T, U>* which caused it to stay a nullptr outside of the Insert function even after calling new and therefore causing an access violation. I'm currently thinking about adding some sort of iterator class to get rid of that warning and to make iterating threadsafe.